# Unknown error pausing the data synchronization in SFMC from CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, crm

Sync in our Client's Marketing Cloud instance has paused a few times now. Not sure why this is happening. It never showed issues earlier until recently, nearly the past 3-4 months ago. The sync pauses for some unknown reason and then it automatically recovers but takes nearly 10 hours of no data syncing into SFMC. Sometimes we manually refresh the sync for the object during the issue.

This happened yesterday and has not recovered yet and when we did the manual refresh, it also did not start from yesterday till today a few minutes ago. It concerns me! Is anyone facing or has faced a similar situation? Any way out of this?

Also, I noticed today the following error continuously popping up: "Marketing Cloud Connected Apps Authentication Error. Synchronization has been paused for all Entities. A synchronization attempt will be executed in one hour. If this error persists please check your Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connected Apps Setup."

I have checked for the setup but it seems proper to me as it should have been.

I have tried looking into the Sync Setup and online documentation for help and raised a Salesforce support ticket but not much help from any of the places.